# java thread visibility

Tags: java, concurrency

When I read the "**java concurrency in practice**" c03, I was confused by the following program:

```
public class NoVisibility { 
    private static boolean ready; 
    private static int number; 

    private static class ReaderThread extends Thread { 
        public void run() { 
            while (!ready) 
                Thread.yield(); 
            System.out.println(number); 
        } 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        new ReaderThread().start(); 
        number = 42; 
        ready = true; 
    } 
}
```

Because of the reordering and thread visibility, the loop may never stop, or the output may be zero, but I have tried many times, and the output is always 42. 
All the reason is I'm too lucky?

Comment: This question is exactly the same as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919469/question-about-java-concurrency-in-practice-example).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> All the reason is I'm too lucky?

Not necessarily. It will depend on your processor architecture and JVM implementation too. That's one of the problems with subtle memory model issues: they can be very hard to reproduce in the wild.

Comment: I do not understand. How cam ready be true before number is set to 42? That is, if no other threads are changing them.

Comment: @Burkhard: Suppose I post two letters to the same person in different post boxes. The one which is posted second may actually reach the recipient before the one which is posted first. The same is true for visibility of memory between threads.