# Why can't I prove that I need an AtomicReference in my code?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have got the following code. Obviously, the Reference class is not thread safe because it does not guard its "reference" attribute. How do I prove that I need to guard it by for example an Atomicreference?

When I run the following JUnit test it suceeds on both Windows: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz and Linux: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5670  @ 2.93GHz using JRE 1.7.0_15.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class AssignReferenceTest {
    private static class Reference {
        private Object reference = null;

        private void setReference(Object reference) {
            this.reference = reference;
        }

        boolean hasReference() {
            return reference != null;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void runManyTimes() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            testReferenceVisibilityProblem();
        }
    }

    public void testReferenceVisibilityProblem() throws Exception {
        final Reference reference = new Reference();
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        Thread writeThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                reference.setReference(new Object());
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
        Thread readThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    latch.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                assertTrue("Should have the reference", reference.hasReference());
            }
        });

        writeThread.start();
        readThread.start();
        writeThread.join();
        readThread.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: How about adding a `sleep(1000)` in front of the
`reference.setReference(new Object());` if you want the test to fail?
Why do you have to prove that it can fail?

Comment: @Buurman Thread.sleep(1000) does not make it fail. I cannot prove I fixed the problem if I cannot prove it exists in the first place.

Comment: Well your latch is making sure that the reference is always set before you test. Resetting it with a different object does not make your test fail nor will ever be null set. You are just replacing an object with another which is completely ignored by your assertTrue statement

Comment: @Matthias the Java Memory Model does not guarantee what you just said, take a look for example at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868187/java-thread-visibility

Comment: @Wojtek Well, that would be true if you would not use the latch to synchronize on the point when your reference surely is initialized. Synchronized blocks ensure that no funny reordering of statements is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is thread-safe, because the CountDownLatch guarantees that every change done before `await()` returns happens before everything done after.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html:

> Actions prior to "releasing" synchronizer methods such as Lock.unlock, Semaphore.release, and CountDownLatch.countDown happen-before actions subsequent to a successful "acquiring" method such as Lock.lock, Semaphore.acquire, Condition.await, and CountDownLatch.await on the same synchronizer object in another thread.