# How to trigger the reordering phenomenon in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

In a book called "Java Concurrency in Practice", I saw a sample code like this at the beginning of chapter 3

```
public class NoVisibility { 
    private static boolean ready; 
    private static int number; 

    private static class ReaderThread extends Thread { 
        public void run() { 
            while (!ready) 
                Thread.yield(); 
            System.out.println(number); 
        } 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        new ReaderThread().start(); 
        number = 42; 
        ready = true; 
    } 
}
```

The book says

"NoVisibility could loop forever because the value of ready might never become visible to the readerthread."

and

"NoVisibility could print zero because the write to ready might be made visible to the readerthread before the write to number, a phenomenon known as reordering."

I'd like to know how to trigger any one of the above events(i.e., loop forever or print zero).

Does anyone know how to make this happen?

I've tried executing this program on my machine(javaSE-1.7 on windows 8.1) for many times. It always print 42 as the result.

Comment: Concurrency issues are notoriously difficult to debug because they can be very difficult to reproduce.  Instead of running the above example as a program that prints out one number and then terminates, why not run it as a subroutine that you call a few million times.  I've done experiments where I called a subroutine a few million times, and it did the wrong thing on maybe ten of those calls.

Comment: On the other hand, sometimes a concurrent program will do the right thing _every_ time you test it... on _your_ system, and then it will do the wrong thing one time out of a million when it's deployed on the customer's system.  That's why you always want to _prove_ it correct, or better yet, reuse somebody else's proven solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java thread visibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868187/java-thread-visibility)

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of mysteries about multithreading, and you'll hurt your head trying to reason why things go wrong. Its easier to just do things right. That being said my elementary understanding is optimizations are made by the machine behind the scene that prevents threads from seeing the latest value posted by another thread. If you need an example just post some sleeping threads and have one change the value and another one read it later. Of the failure occurs there will be two different values for the supposed single value.