# How do visibility problems occur in Java concurrency?

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrent-programming

I am reading the book: "Java Concurrency in Practice" to better understand how java concurrency works. On chapter 3 section 3.1:Visibility There is and example in which the book tries to show how visibility problems occur. Here is the example code (Listing 3.1 in the book):

```
public class NoVisibility {
    private static boolean ready;
    private static int number;

    private static class ReaderThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            while (!ready)
                Thread.yield();
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ReaderThread().start();
        number = 42;
        ready = true;
    }
}
```

The book says that the NoVisibility could loop forever because the    value of ready might never become visible to the reader thread. How    is that possible. My general understanding is that ready will become    true at a certain time anyhow. But I can't understand why this might    not happen and the loop goes forever. Can someone help me to    understand this better.

Comment: BTW it is the first question under Related. Have you searched before posting this?

Comment: apparently you don't know what "-1" is for. you can vote for close.but "-1" for a valid question is not fair.

Comment: Moreover, the question in that link is not really clear. naturally you go for reading meaningful questions. not very general ones. still don't understand the -1.

Comment: @Hossein The tooltip over the -1 mentions lack of research as a possible downvote motivation. Not clicking the links SO is basically shoving down your  face as you author your question would count. (Not the downvoter, just that it's a likely explanation.)

Comment: @Hossein: how is a question useful if it is nearly verbatim the same as a question that has been asked already? Does it show research effort?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because ready isn't marked as volatile and the value may be cached at the start of the while loop because it isn't changed within the while loop. It's one of the ways the jitter optimizes the code.

So it's possible that the thread starts before ready = true and reads ready = false caches that thread-locally and never reads it again.

Check out the volatile keyword.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1919476/12860)

Comment: Burkhard i have question for you after going thru various answers given at the link you posted.Does thread always caches the instance variable to optimize the performance (or its nor certain behaviour)?Another thing performance we are talking about here is in  terms of code execution time. Right?

Comment: @MSach: It is possible that it will be cached, but it may also not be cached (it is up to the JVM). The only way to be sure, is to declare it volatile. I'm not sure if I understand your second question. What other performances are there?