# Visibility issue in java concurrent programming

Tags: java, concurrency, memory-visibility

I came across following example in book 'Java Concurrency in Practice'.

```
public class NoVisibility {
    private static boolean ready;
    private static int number;

    private static class ReaderThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
           while (!ready)
              Thread.yield();
           System.out.println(number);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ReaderThread().start();
        number = 42;
        ready = true;
     }
}
```

Its stated further as:

> NoVisibility could loop forever because the value of ready might never become
>   visible to the reader thread. Even more strangely, NoVisibility could print
>   zero because the write to ready might be made visible to the reader thread before
>   the write to number, a phenomenon known as reordering.

I can understand reordering issue, but I a not able to comprehend the visibility issue. Why the value of `ready` might never become visible to reader thread? Once main thread writes value in `ready`, sooner or later reader thread would get its chance to run and it can read value of `ready`. Why is it that change made by main thread in `ready` might not be visible to reader thread?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322527/how-do-visibility-problems-occur-in-java-concurrency

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [question about "Java Concurrency in Practice" example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919469/question-about-java-concurrency-in-practice-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReaderThread`'s `run()` method may never see the latest value of `ready` because it's free to assume and optimize that the value will not change outside of it's thread. This assumption can be taken away by using the relevant concurrency features of the language like adding the keyword `volatile` to `ready`'s declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a new problem that started happening with multi-core CPUs and separate CPU caches.

There would be no need to worry if you were actually reading and modifying memory, and even with multi-CPUs you'd be safe except that each CPU now has it's own cache.  The memory location would be cached and the other thread will never see it because it will be operating exclusively out of the cache.

When you make it volatile it forces both threads to go directly to memory every time--so it slows things down quite a bit but it's thread safe.