# How to "pause" the application properly until state change in Java?

Tags: java

I have to "pause" my application until the socket receive a certain message from an other application.

```
public class Status {
    public static boolean ready = false;
}

public class Application
{
    public void method()
    {
       // do job
       // wait other app is ready

       while(Status.ready == false)
       {
           // do nothing

           // [[ 1 ]] 
       }

       // continue

    }
}

public class SocketImpl extends Thread
{
   ...
   // It is expected that the other program is ready
   public void run()
   {
      // receive some msg
      // if it's ready message
      Status.ready = true;
   }
}
```

Ok so, I think you understand what i do, now 2 questions

1. Using while is it properly ? what is the best practice.
2. About java mechanisms, why my while() doesn't detect change state of the boolean in this configuration ? and why if I replace `// [[ 1 ]]` by `System.out.println(Status.ready)` it works?

Add a `println` allows `while` to detect the change of state. Why? I can't explain that.

Comment: No, this isn't a good approach--it's called a busy wait. You might want to use some sort of notification.

Comment: Ok, about the approach, it's really ugly. Considering this, even if it's bad approach what about the question 2 ? I especially asked for it, I suspected that this was the wrong approach.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919469/question-about-java-concurrency-in-practice-example

Comment: You could consider a [SynchronousQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) or an [ArrayBlockingQueue(1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#ArrayBlockingQueue%28int%29) but `Observer` pattern would be better.

Comment: The approach was ugly, but that was for some test that s why i haven't implement some kind of observer pattern, volatile keyword was the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This busy waiting approach is not good. You should implement the *Observer* pattern so when SocketImpl has a message it notifies it's attached observers.

First define an observer interface:

```
interface SocketObserver {
     public void MessageReceived(Object aMessage);
}
```

Where aMessage might be an instance of a custom class holding the message data.

Then in your SocketImpl define an observer(muliple can be supported using arraylist)

```
public class SocketImpl extends Thread
{
   private SocketObserver observer;

   public void setObserver(SocketObserver observer) {
         this.observer = observer;
   }

   // It is expected that the other program is ready
   public void run()
   {
      // receive some msg
      // if it's ready message
      observer.MessageReceived(yourMessageHere); //Notify the observer that a message is received
   }
}
```

Then before you start the thread do set the observer property.

```
SocketImpl socket = new SocketImpl();
socket.setObserver(new SocketObserver() {
      @Override
      public void MessageReceived(Object message) {
              //Message received do something with it
      }
});

socket.start();
```

You can see more info implementing the Observer pattern here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern