# Findbugs: NP_LOAD_OF_KNOWN_NULL_VALUE - Singleton class Double checking

Tags: java, findbugs

I have a Singleton class with double checking in the constructor.

Findbugs is reporting the below error.

**`Load of known null value in ... NP_LOAD_OF_KNOWN_NULL_VALUE`**

```
class SomeClass {
  private Object lock = new Object();
  private Map<String,Resource> resourceMap = new HashMap<>();

  public Resource getResource(String resourceId) {
    if (resourceMap.get(resourceId) == null) {
      synchronized(lock) {
        if (resourceMap.get(resourceId) == null) 
          Resource resource = new Resource();
          resourceMap.put(resourceId,resource);
      }
    }
    return resourceMap.get(resourceId);
  }
}
```

I can go with a static object reference, but the requirement is to create a single object for a unique request ids.

Say, request id 1 will be there for multiple request. So, we will have to create a single object for all request ids at run time for this.

Thanks,

Comment: There is no notion of the «request id» in the source code. Could you please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: It doesn't look legal to have `synchronized` in this context without an argument, e.g. `synchronized(this)`.  (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19) Could you make sure you're showing us the correct code?

Comment: Sorry, did not put the complete code. Have updated now.

Comment: Please see https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html and https://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/bugs/1283/.  Apparently, double-checked locking is not guaranteed to work, and because of that, the findbugs people think this behavior is OK.  There's a suggestion that things might work if you declare the variable you're checking to be `volatile`, but I don't know whether that will work if the variable is an element in a collection.  Try adding `volatile` anyway and see if that works.

Comment: How the `resourceMap` field is initialised?

Comment: Missed that `resourceMap` is never set.  That could be the source of the findbugs error.

Comment: Oops ... Updated my post. It is initialized.

Comment: @ajb it is perfectly legal and valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a ConcurrentMap instead of the double check locking pattern. Your method is not correct with respect to the visibility of elements of the Map (see the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919469/question-about-java-concurrency-in-practice-example) for more details about visibility).

```
class SomeClass {
  private final ConcurrentMap<String, Resource> resourceMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public Resource getResource(String resourceId) {
      return resourceMap.computeIfAbsent(resourceId, r -> new Resource());
  }

  private static class Resource {}
}
```

**Edit to limit to 10 elements with LRU replacement strategy**

You can use [Guava cache](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) that uses LRU strategy for default [size-based eviction](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#size-based-eviction).

```
import com.google.common.cache.*;

class SomeClass {
    private final LoadingCache<String, Resource> resourceMap =
            CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                    .maximumSize(10L)
                    .build(new CacheLoader<String, Resource>() {
                        @Override
                        public Resource load(String key) {
                            return new Resource();
                        }
                    });

    public Resource getResource(String resourceId) {
        return resourceMap.getUnchecked(resourceId);
    }

    private static class Resource {
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to limit the number of entries to 10 and when we try to add the 11th entry, the LRU should be cleaned up. So, thought of using weekreference. But, How can i achieve this with the ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: What if initialization of `resource` is a long running, expensive process? Your approach allows multiple times of `resource` to be initialized and only single instance will be indeed put into the map.

Comment: @Antoniossss To limit to only one instance instantiated, you have to get a global lock and serialise all the access to the `getResource` method. It has an impact on every accesses while the approach I have described has impact only on the first accesses (if they are concurrent access while the resource was not yet created). It depends on your use case but I think this approach has a lower impact in general.

Comment: @user1578872 I have made an edit with an approach to limit to 10 elements using Guava library.

Comment: @NicolasHenneaux that is why double-check-locking is used for. Simply speaking - your approach is not universal and will not work in high concurent env.

Comment: @Antoniossss As I said in my answer double-check locking in this case is broken with respect to the visibility of the Map elements. That is why I propose another pattern.

Comment: @NicolasHenneaux Broken double-check-locking happens in different scenario - the exact particular one that is described in papers - here it will work.

Comment: Actually, Creating Resource is an expensive and time consuming operation. Hope, even during the loading time, there will be only one instance for the given key.