# Threads can't get the access to shareable resource in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I can't get to understand why the shared list in Consumers is always empty while the Provider adds values to it.
I have the Provider:

```
class Provider extends Thread {
    List<Integer> products;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    public Provider(List<Integer> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Provider just generate random value and adds the value to the shared list
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Integer product = rnd.nextInt(100);
            System.out.println("added value: "+product);
            products.add(product);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the the Consumer:

```
class Consumer extends Thread {
    List<Integer> products;

    public Consumer(List<Integer> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Consumer started");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5;) {
            //Consumer just removes elements from shared list five times
            if (!products.isEmpty()) {
                Integer product = products.remove(0);
                System.out.println("removed: "+product);
                i++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Consumer stopped");
    }
}
```

In the main I have the following:

```
List<Integer> products = new ArrayList<>();
new Provider(products).start();
new Consumer(products).start();
new Consumer(products).start();
```

I supposed each Consumer should read five values from shareable list after the Provider adds values to it, but in the Consumers the list is always empty. Why the list isn't being updated?

I get the following result:

```
Consumer started
Consumer started
added value: 13
removed: 13
removed: 13
added value: 28
added value: 53
added value: 32
added value: 85
added value: 23
added value: 60
added value: 10
added value: 15
added value: 85
```

After the Provider has finished the Consumers are working but can't remove any item because of the condition.

Please don't write about synchronisation. I understand that the threads should synchronize the access to common resource. But it's study example and my goal is to make the Consumers read and remove the values from list.

Comment: Synchronization may be relevant because it makes visibility guarantees.

Comment: It looks like both threads try to remove the same item from the list. That seems like it would cause an exception. You definitely should check to see if your consumers are completing. I would also suggest synchronizing access to the list when you add/remove.

Comment: You should just use a BlockingQueue for this anyways.

Comment: @Nathan Hughes what do you mean by visibility?

Comment: This is literally what a [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) is for (or some sort of [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) as matt says if you want to provide backpressure).

Comment: Visibility means that when multiple threads are accessing the same data, changes made by one are not necessarily visible to the other. [Visibility problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919469/question-about-java-concurrency-in-practice-example) can occur because unless there is synchonization or volatility, the JVM is free to assume values have not changed, and fail to write changes all the way to memory, or flush cache lines when reading from memory, or use a value stored in a register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the first comment hits the nail on the head. Without *any* synchronization then the threads are not guaranteed to see an update. Especially with a tight loop like that.

Adding synchronized to the consumer works for me.

```java
class Consumer extends Thread {
    List<Integer> products;

    public Consumer(List<Integer> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Consumer started");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5;) {
            //Consumer just removes elements from shared list five times
            synchronized(products){
                if (!products.isEmpty()) {
                    Integer product = products.remove(0);
                    System.out.println("removed: "+product);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Consumer stopped");
    }
}
```

When I tried this without synchronization the consumers never take from the list.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, but I don't understand why the list isn't being updated. The list isn't a primitive value, it's passed by the link. So the threads shouldn't cache the link of the list. So I can't get why the list isn't being updated

Comment: @AlexanderTukanov Java's `List` implementation is [an interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).  Not all implementing classes are thread-safe.

Comment: @AlexanderTukanov what is most likely happening is that the JIT compiler is smart enough to know that once isEmpty() returns true one time, it will always return true unless items are added to the list, and since there's no code *in the loop* in the consumer than can add anything to the list, it feels free to cache the return value of isEmpty() for performance reasons. But you would have to check the disassembly of the native code to be sure.

Comment: @AlexanderTukanov, Re, "the threads shouldn't cache the link..." They _do_ cache it. If one thread updates anything in memory (e.g., fields of an object) in the absence of any so-called "synchronization," then there is no guarantee of when or even _if_ other threads will see the update happen. The simplest form of synchronization is a `synchronized(o)` block: If one thread updates things while inside `synchronized(o)`, and then some other thread subsequently enters `synchronized(o)` on the same object `o`, then the second thread _IS_ guaranteed to see the updates.